# Intento que una tabla de html se comporte como una hoja de cálculo

Tags: html

Estoy intentando que una tabla editable de html se comporte de manera similar a como lo haría una de Excel, principalmente que haga las siguientes cosas: separar el texto que pegue en una celda y las reparta en otras, y que genere más columnas y filas para que el texto quepa, saltar de una fila a la de abajo al presionar Enter, y por último, que se vea la separación de las celdas, porque desapareció cuando agregué el `contenteditable`.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> exportar html a excel</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.16.9/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/file-saverjs@latest/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport@latest/dist/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<br><br>

<-la tabla->
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
             exportar datos de html a excel
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <button id="btnExportar" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Exportar datos a Excel
            </button> 

            <table id="tabla" class="table table-border table-hover" contenteditable='true'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    const $btnExportar = document.querySelector("#btnExportar"),
        $tabla = document.querySelector("#tabla");

    $btnExportar.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let tableExport = new TableExport($tabla, {
            exportButtons: false, 
            filename: "Reporte de prueba",
            sheetname: "Reporte de prueba",
        });
        let datos = tableExport.getExportData();
        let preferenciasDocumento = datos.tabla.xlsx;
        tableExport.export2file(preferenciasDocumento.data, preferenciasDocumento.mimeType, preferenciasDocumento.filename, preferenciasDocumento.fileExtension, preferenciasDocumento.merges, preferenciasDocumento.RTL, preferenciasDocumento.sheetname);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y puntualmente, cual es el problema?

Comment: no encuentro la manera de generar celdas de una tabla html desde la página

Comment: Te refieres a esta parte "Saltar de una fila a la de abajo al presionar Enter" ????

Comment: sí, me gustaría saber si hay una forma de que una fila se añada al presionar Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo más fácil es ir guardando el número de la fila en los tr, esto lo hago en un atributo data-row. También en el evento keypress que detecta si se presionó la tecla "enter" (cuyo keycode es 13) enviamos el número de la fila y el número de la columna.

Cuando se presiona "enter" pueden pasar 2 cosas:

1. Si estamos en la última fila se crea una fila nueva, y además se hace foco en esa nueva fila, y en la misma columna anterior
2. No se está en la última fila, aquí solo se hace foco en la siguiente fila y en la misma columna

```js
const TABLA = document.getElementById("Tabla");

function presskey(row,col){
    if (event.keyCode === 13){ //se presionó enter ??
        
        let newRowId = row + 1;
        event.preventDefault();

        let Filas = TABLA.querySelectorAll("tr");

        if (row === Filas.length) { //estoy en la última fila??
            //Si -> agrego nueva fila
            CrearNuevaFila(newRowId, col, Filas);
        }
        else{
            //No -> Hago focus a la fila de abajo
            focus(newRowId, col);
        }

    }
    
}
function CrearNuevaFila(row,col, Filas){
            
    let tr =  document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("data-row", row);

    let Columnas = Filas[0].querySelectorAll("td");
    for(let i = 1; i <= Columnas.length; i++){
        let td = document.createElement("td");
        td.contentEditable=true;
        td.setAttribute("onkeypress", "presskey(" + row + ","+i+")");
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    TABLA.appendChild(tr);
    focus(row, col);
}
function focus(row,col){
    document.querySelector("tr[data-row='" + row  + "']").querySelectorAll("td")[col - 1].focus();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <tbody id="Tabla">
        <tr data-row="1">
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,1)"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,2)"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,3)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```